# Requests Retry: will same proxy be used

Tags: python, python-requests

I keep seeing examples similar to this for adding retries when using the Requests library. However, I'm unsure of whether Requests will execute `choice(my_proxy_list)` at every retry and thus get a new proxy or just keep retrying with the same arguments used for initial request.

```
import my_proxy_list
from random import choice
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

session = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=0.4, status_forcelist=[400, 429, 500, 502, 503, 504])
session.mount("http://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
response = session.get(
    url=url,
    proxies=choice(my_proxy_list),
    timeout=(10, 27),
)
session.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function arguments are evaluated once, regardless of what that function goes on to do later (including any retry logic that function may use internally), so `random.choice` will only be called once in your example.

The best option if you want a (chance at a) different proxy each time is to do your own retry logic which calls `random.choice` each time. To guarantee a different proxy each time, you could shuffle the list of possible proxies at the start and then traverse it.

Alternatively, it would be possible to pass in a dictionary-like object for `proxies` with a `__getitem__` designed to return a random proxy each time, but that approach isn't recommended as it'd be very fragile and would rely heavily on the implementation details of `session.get`.